# API url conflict when using localization

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, razor-pages, minimal-apis

I have an ASPNET Razor pages app where i use localization; i would also need to use the same application to expose some API endpoints using minimal APIs.
With this class:

```
public class CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;

        for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
        {
            var selector = model.Selectors[i];
               
            model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Order = -1,
                    Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{culture?}", selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template),
                }
            });
                
        }
    }
}
```

urls for links are generated with the language, as:   en/Products , en/Customers and it works fine.

The problem is that when I create a

```
app.MapPost("/api/Customers", () =>
{
   return "TEST FROM API";
});
```

user is redirected to Login page instead of returning JSON because "Customers" is part of selectors used for normal urls , while:

```
app.MapPost("/api/APICustomers", () =>
{
   return "TEST FROM API";
});
```

works fine because APICustomers is not part of knows urls.

I would like to avoid to use bad names like XYZCustomers, but would like to POST /api/Customers ... is there a way?

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] somewhere like github?